# iPhone UIStoryBoard is it possible to programmatically create a controller with interface defined in a storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a bunch of view controllers defined within a UIStoryBoard. I like having all of them in one place for easy access. However, I ran into an issue where I need to instantiate a copy of a view controller at some other place within the app. **Is it possible to programmatically create a UIViewController using the interface for it that is defined within a storyboard?**

Otherwise I would have to copy the storyboard view for that controller into a separate .xib file and load the view manually.

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

Yup, and it's not too bad at all!  `-instantiateInitialViewController` is what you're looking for.

A helper I tend to use is:

```
- (void) loadStoryboard:(NSString *)storyboardName animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  if ([_currentStoryboard isEqual:storyboardName])
  {
    return;
  }

  _currentStoryboard = storyboardName;

  UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
  UIViewController* newRootController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

  if (!animated)
  {
    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
    return;
  }

  newRootController.view.alpha = 0.0;
  [self.window addSubview:newRootController.view];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    newRootController.view.alpha = 1.0;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.window.rootViewController = newRootController;
  }];
}
```

This variant is set up for the dumping ground that is your `AppDelegate` - should be easily adaptable to most situations, though.

Comment: I was looking to load a specific view controller defined within a storyboard, not an initial one. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, the other method on UIStoryboard that might help you is `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`.  You might want to consider breaking things into multiple storyboards, though (if it makes sense in your context) - so far that pattern has been really helpful on my projects